# How to join two similar dataframes and apply conditions python vs sql

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, join, sas

I have done a code on SAS Eguide (SQL) and I am trying to do the same in python.
My idea is to join two similar dataframes but apply some conditions.

This is my code on SAS:

```
SELECT * 
 FROM SASUSER.df1 t1
  LEFT JOIN SASUSER.df2 t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id) AND (t1.Id_Claim = t2.Id_Claim) AND 
                            (t1.Id_Seq_No_Linha = t2.Id_Seq_No_Linha) AND 
                            (t1.Dt_Inicio_Ato = t2.Dt_Inicio_Ato) AND 
                            (t1.Id_Procedimento_Servico_ = t2.Id_Procedimento_Servico_)
    WHERE NOT (t1.id = t2.id AND t1.Id_Claim = t2.Id_Claim AND 
               t1.Id_Seq_No_Linha = t2.Id_Seq_No_Linha AND t1.Dt_Inicio_Ato =  t2.Dt_Inicio_Ato
               AND t1.Id_Procedimento_Servico =t2.Id_Procedimento_Servico_M);
QUIT;
```

While trying to do the same thing in python, I have encountered multiple errors or it just does not work the way I want. I have tried to merge, but when I merge ON the variables, there is no WHERE condition to apply because there is only one variable. The append/concat puts more rows than it is supposed to and does not work, and I have also tried the following, for example:

```
cond1 = df1['id']!=df2['id'] #also tried cond1 = ~(df1['id'].isin[df2['id'])
df3 = df1[(cond1)]
```

but it returns this error: ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects.

Can you help me, please? My goal is to delete the information of df2 from df1 based on those conditions.

Comment: your  tables probably have different indices, try `.set_index('id')` before comparing them. for the rest of the question it might be helpful to get example tables, it's quite difficult to get an idea what's going wrong and why

Comment: @PatrickH. Thank you. I already tried it but it returns a key error: 'id', because it is one of the conditions and id is not a "column" anymore

Comment: @PatrickH. I also tried to duplicate the id columns, but it returns the value error: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: Okay, so your `id` column already is part of the index? Indices are no normal columns, you need to use `df.index` zu access it. Alternatively you can do the opposite operation with `.reset_index()`. But then the columns might be `df["index"]` if not named previously. As said, would be really helpful to get a small example set of your tables

Comment: The error you see comes from comparing two series with a different set of indices. But if i get that correctly that's what you want to compare. So maybe you can try and `align` your tables before comparing like `df.align(df2, axis=0)` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.align.html

Comment: I think a left outer join works for what I need: ````pd.merge(df1, df2[['id','Id_Claim','Id_Seq_No_Linha','Dt_Inicio_Ato','Id_Procedimento_Servico_']], on=['id','Id_Claim','Id_Seq_No_Linha','Dt_Inicio_Ato','Id_Procedimento_Servico_'],
                    how="outer", indicator=True).query('_merge=="left_only"')````